# Error When sending an email using the EmailJS with react hook form

Tags: reactjs

I built a form using "react-hook-form", and now at the moment of the submit I want to send a email using mailjs, but it is returning me these errors:

```
sendPost.js:22 POST https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send-form 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
The recipient address is empty
```

Here's my function to send the email:

```
const sendEmail = (e) => {    

    emailjs.sendForm('ServiceID', 'TemplateID', form.current, 'USERID')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
          alert("Sucess!")
          navigate('/results')
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
      
  };
```

And here is my form:

```
return(
        <div className='box'>
            <div className='login-section'></div>
                <div className='login-text'>Thanks for answering the quiz, your score is {location.state.score} Please insert your name and email to send the results</div>
                <form ref={form} onSubmit={handleSubmit(sendEmail)}>
                    <label>
                        Name
                        <input type='text' name='user_name' {...register("name", { required: true })}/>
                        <span>{errors.name?.message}</span>
                        
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Email
                        <input type='text' name='user_email' {...register("email" , { required: true })}/>
                        <span>{errors.email?.message}</span>
                    </label>
                        <input type='hidden' name='score' value={location.state.score}/>
                    <button type='submit'>Send</button>
                </form>
        </div>
    )
```

Not sure what's happening here, for me it seems all correct, any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `onSubmit={sendEmail}` should do the work for you.